# Load XML file from external server using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am new to AS3, I need to know how to load a xml file from Local server.

Answer (score 1):

Lee Brimelow has a good tutorial on [loading XML](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=242). You should just be able to pass your XML's full path to the URLRequest object. But make sure the external server has a cross domain file setup, or you won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for this kind of question could be the AS3 docs. As you progress with AS3, the docs will become an essential tool.

In this specific case you would want to look at the [URLLoader Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html)
and probably have a look at the [XML Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).

You should find typical use examples such as [this one](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#includeExamplesSummary) which loads a simple text file, although the general implementation will be very similar for an XML file.

Since you're a beginner, you would probaly like to check the video tutorials on [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/show/actionscript-11-with-doug-winnie/) as well as Lee Brimelow's website [gotoandlearn.com](http://gotoandlearn.com/)  (as referred to by Adam ) which is filled with excellent resources.